# Where does $u(t,x) \to u(t,x)-a-(b-a)x$ come from?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I know the heat equation is $$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} u(t,x)=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} u(t,x)$$

I know that $u(t,x)$ is the temperature distribution at time $t$ at the point $x$.

We assume that the temperature at $x=0$ and $x=1$ is fixed.

In the notes then it says

"consider $u(t,x) \to u(t,x)-a-(b-a)x$ and it is clear that $a=b=0$"

Why do we consider this and where does $u(t,x)-a-(b-a)$ come from?

And how can we see $a=b=0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the form of the heat equation you can always add an arbitrary first-degree polynomial in $x.$ That freedom is used to satisfy the *inhomogeneous* boundary conditions (temperature at the end points known but not necessarily zero) when a hypothetical solution with *homogeneous* boundary conditions $t(0)=t(1)=0$ is supposed known.